# ind min and max of $\sum_{1\leq i<j\leq n} (3 \min\{j-i,n+i-j\}-n)x_ix_j$

Tags: inequality

Let n be a fixed positive odd number and $x_1, x_2,\cdots,x_n \in [-1,1]$. Find min and max of$$\sum_{1\leq i<j\leq n} (3 \min\{j-i,n+i-j\}-n)x_ix_j$$

Could someone give me a hint?

Comment: First, because the expression is linear in each of the variables $x_i$ its maximum and minimum should be in the boundry of $[-1, 1]$. Also at the maximum if $x_ix_j=1$ then $j-i$ should be closer to $n/2$ (the opposite for the minimum)

Comment: Also if you take $k=n/2$ then the coefficient is equal to $k-3|k-(j-i)|$. This is why when you are looking for the maximum you always want $x_ix_j=1$ whenever $j-i$ is closer to $k$.